# Passing null to a destructive method in Java

Tags: java, parameters, null

I plan to implement a destructively catenation function in Java like `public static void dcatenate(IntList A, IntList B)`, which is used to append list B to A, and the original A should be modified. For example,

```
IntList A = new IntList(1,2,3); // A: 1->2->3
IntList B = new IntList(4,5,6); // B: 4->5->6
dcatenate(A, B) // A: 1->2->3->4->5->6
```

However, what if `A=null`?

```
IntList A = null;
IntList B = new IntList(4,5,6); // B: 4->5->6
dcatenate(A, B) // A: 4->5->6 (is it possible?)
```

Since the function parameter is passed by value, I cannot locate the original A in the function when I pass null to the parameter. Moreover, modifying the parameter A will never change the original A because they are stored in different addresses although they are both null. Is my understanding correct? If so, how can I solve this problem? Is it possible to pass the address of original A to the parameter just like C/C++?

Comment: it is impossible in java, as it pass by value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. You can solve this problem by initializing `A` to an empty list instead of `null`. This will also avoid NPEs and reduce the need for `!= null` checks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you change the arguments of dcatenate() to

```
list = dcatenate(list);
```

where the list contains the IntList A and B.

This way you can keep the references intact.

I wouldn't see this as a restriction. This is just one of way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the null reference to be an object instance. The value of `A` may not even be a variable at all -- perhaps the calling code looks like:

```
dcatenate(getListA(), getListB());
```

In that case there is literally no way for `dcatenate` to communicate a new object instance back to its caller.

In this particular case, it sounds like a precondition of your `dcatenate` function is that the `A` argument must be a mutable list. `null` is not a mutable list, and so `dcatenate` should throw an exception (possibly an `IllegalArgumentException` or possibly a `NullPointerException`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having your `dcatenate` method return a new list instead of attempting to modify the parameters directly, for the reasons you mention. And then you can simply assign the result back to `A` if you want.

Example:

```
IntList A = null;
IntList B = new IntList(4,5,6); // B: 4->5->6
A = dcatenate(A, B);
```